# How to fetch key value pairs from IDictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a jSon file which contains some values like this:

```
{AvailableWeapons:[ {"LevelNumber":1,"WeaponName":"Axe"},{"LevelNumber":5,"WeaponName":"WarHammer"} ]
```

Using miniJSon, I have parsed this into an IDictionary as follows:

```
IDictionary weaponsGrid = JsonManager.instance.availableWeapons as IDictionary;
```

I'm accessing this in a method that has an integer parameter "level". The method takes the parameter, compares it with each levelnumber field. If level is greater than levelNumber, the corresponding weapon is made available.

PseudoCode:

```
foreach levelNumber in weaponsGrid,
if currentLevel > levelNumber
 get name of weapon available at that level
```

how can I accomplish this in C#? thanks

Comment: What's the key for your dictionary?

Comment: That would be levelnumber

Comment: Wait, is just a single weapon made available? If so, dictionary is wrong for a start because the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: No, multiple weapons will be available. E.g one weapon is unlocked at level 5, one more at level 15, another at level 20. So, if current leavel is 21, all three weapons are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use the [`Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property like

```
foreach(var levelNumber in weaponsGrid.Keys)
{
   // your code here    
}
```

You can access the value using the key

```
weaponsGrid[levelNumber]
```

Considering you have your dictionary set up

```
        IDictionary<int, string> weaponsGrid = new Dictionary<int, string> 
        { 
        { 1, "Axe" }, 
        { 6, "WarHammer" }, 
        { 2, "Knife" }, 
        { 9, "Gun" } 
        };
```

You can check if a key exists and then get it's value like

```
        string weapon = weaponsGrid.ContainsKey(6) ? weaponsGrid[6] : string.Empty;
```

Or, get all the values

```
        foreach (var item in weaponsGrid.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);

        }
```

Comment: How would I go about accessing weapon name for that levelNumber?

Comment: You can use the key to access a value. See edit in answer.

Comment: This has an unnecessary dictionary lookup though

Comment: I don't follow. This: `weaponsGrid[levelNumber]` is the unnecessary look up. And `weaponsGrid.Values` is no good to OP as they need the key too for filtering.

Comment: @weston, You shouldn't consider that. I shown that to let OP know, how a value can be accessed using key (see first comment in answer). Probably, rest of logic OP can figure out by himself.

Comment: Fine, but you didn't address the unnecessary dictionary lookup then.

Answer (score 4):

Using linq:

```
IDictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "Axe" }, { 6, "WarHammer" }, { 2, "Knife" }, { 9, "Gun" } };

var list = dict.Where(x => x.Key > 5).Select(x=> x.Value)
            .ToList();
```

this gives you a list of values where the key is larger the X

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
IDictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "Axe" }, { 6, "WarHammer" }, { 2, "Knife" }, { 9, "Gun" } };

int level = 5; //input to method
List<string> powerfulWeapons = new List<string>(); //method output
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    if (item.Key > level)
        powerfulWeapons.Add(item.Value);
}
//powerfulWeapons = [ "WarHammer", "Gun" ]
```

Or, using `Linq`

```
var weapons = weaponsGrid.Where(w => w.Key > 5).Select(d => d.Value);
```

In case you want just one

```
string firstHeavyWeapon = string.Empty;
var firstHeavyWeaponEntry = weaponsGrid.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Key > 5);
if (!firstHeavyWeaponEntry.Equals(new KeyValuePair<int, string>()))
    firstHeavyWeapon = firstHeavyWeaponEntry.Value;
```

As suggested in comments, if you want first (minimum) `Key` matching the criteria, you can do this

```
var firstHeavyWeaponEntry = weaponsGrid
                                .OrderBy(w => w.Key)
                                .FirstOrDefault(w => w.Key > 5);
```

Comment: Assuming `weaponsGrid` is the dictionary: I removed my up vote now because of the `First...` lookup, because now you're relying on the order inside a dictionary. Insert `.OrderBy(x => x.Key)` before the `First...` and you're good.

Comment: @weston that is not specified by OP as a criteria as such, but added in answer in case he wants that. Thanks.

Comment: My point is that the behaviour is unpredictable when relying the order in the dictionary. Predictable behaviour is **by default** a criteria from an OP!

Comment: You see, `Dictionary` is under no obligation to maintain the order that the items were add to it. (That's why there is a separate [`SortedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx)) But I guess it is wrong to assume to order it one way or another when they haven't specified.

Comment: "For purposes of enumeration... The order in which the items are returned is undefined." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @weston yes I agree. My point is, unless OP specifies a specific requirement, and he wants "any one" weapon matching the level criteria, `OrderBy` is not required. But, I see the problem now, I mean *"just one"*, not *"just the first one"*. Edited the answer to clear the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in weaponsGrid.Keys)
  if (item > levelNumber) {
    string weapon = weaponsGrid[item];
  }
```

Comment: This has an unnecessary dictionary lookup though

Answer (score 1):

use the KeyValuePair

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Int32,string> weapen in weaponsGrid )
  {
    if(weapen.key > value)
    {
            var weapenName = weapen.Value
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the keys in your dictionary by using the `IDictionary.Keys` property which returns an `ICollection` of your keys. For your example you would do something like:

```
foreach (var levelNumber in weaponsGrid.Keys)
{
    if (currentLevel > levelNumber)
    {
        var weaponName = weaponsGrid[levelNumber].Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has an unnecessary dictionary lookup though

Comment: @weston Yes it does. But only if we hit the if statement. Plus I'd expect the dictionary lookup to be relatively quick. Seeing that we do not actually require having the value outside of the `if` statement I'd argue that the `foreach` over the keys is more readable until we actually require anything else.

Comment: It might pass that `if` every time, or never. I don't think readability is an issue at all in the enumeration over all `KeyValuePairs` answers.